# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, utf-8, base64, decode

I'm trying to decode the following string in Python:

```
61PGlmcmFtZSB0aXRsZT0ib2sgdmlkZW8gcGxheWVyIiBzcmM9Ii8vb2sucnUvdmlkZW9lbWJlZC82MzI5MjYyOTM0NjkwP2F1dG9wbGF5PTEiIGlkPSJwbGFjZWhvbGRlciIgYWxsb3d0cmFuc3BhcmVuY3k9InRydWUiIHNjcm9sbGJhcnM9Im5vIiB0cmFuc3BhcmVudD0ieWVzIiBmcmFtZWJvcmRlcj0iMCIgYWxsb3c9ImVuY3J5cHRlZC1tZWRpYSAqOyBhdXRvcGxheTsgZnVsbHNjcmVlbiIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iNDgwIiBzY3JvbGxpbmc9Ik5vIiAgYWxsb3dmdWxsc2NyZWVuPjwvaWZyYW1lPg==
```

However, I'm getting this error with "utf-8" (other encoding options give invalid output):

```
Text\decode test.py", line 7, in <module>
    decoded_string = decoded_bytes.decode("utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

The correct decoded string should look like:

```
<a iframe title="ok video player" src="//ok.ru/videoembed/6329262934690?autoplay=1" id="player" allowfullscreen="true" fullscreen="" width="100%" height="480" scrolling="no" allow="encrypted-media" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have tried multiple online decoding tools as well but I didn't get any correct answer.
Only ChatGPT was able to give me the correct decoded string; However, when I ask for the procedure, I keep on getting the same python code I'm using as well:

```
import base64

encoded_string = "61PGlmcmFtZSB0aXRsZT0ib2sgdmlkZW8gcGxheWVyIiBzcmM9Ii8vb2sucnUvdmlkZW9lbWJlZC82MzI5MjYyOTM0NjkwP2F1dG9wbGF5PTEiIGlkPSJwbGFjZWhvbGRlciIgYWxsb3d0cmFuc3BhcmVuY3k9InRydWUiIHNjcm9sbGJhcnM9Im5vIiB0cmFuc3BhcmVudD0ieWVzIiBmcmFtZWJvcmRlcj0iMCIgYWxsb3c9ImVuY3J5cHRlZC1tZWRpYSAqOyBhdXRvcGxheTsgZnVsbHNjcmVlbiIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iNDgwIiBzY3JvbGxpbmc9Ik5vIiAgYWxsb3dmdWxsc2NyZWVuPjwvaWZyYW1lPg=="

decoded_bytes = base64.b64decode(encoded_string)
decoded_string = decoded_bytes.decode("utf-8")

print(decoded_string)
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: *encoded_string* is clearly a Base64 representation of something. Whatever it is, it's not UTF-8. In fact, none of the 97 well-known encodings will produce the output you're expecting

Comment: @DarkKnight I have already tried multiple decoding options including Latin-1 but all of them just give random invalid output. I'm still wondering how only ChatGPT was able to decode this and It didn't give me any correct clue to it.

Comment: ChatGPT has obviously found a resource (somewhere) that states (incorrectly) that the Base 64 string represents that HTML fragment and ChatGPT believes that to be the truth when, in fact, it isn't. ChatGPT doesn't always get things right

Comment: @DarkKnight the answer that ChatGPT gave is legit and correct as I have tested it from the website where I get this encoded string. I have also asked him to decode another similar string (55PGlmcmFtZSB0aXRsZT0idm8gdmVsb....) and it gave me the correct decoding as well: <a href="vo video player" src="https://voe.sx/e/thwqzajyih7i7" id="player" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" transparent="yes" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>. So, obviously he knows how to decode but can't tell how!

Comment: Where did you get you base64? It could help us

Comment: @jeremiebergeron Here is a sample url from the website where I got these encoded strings: https://www.tv-f.com/video/ikhwati-s3-modablaj-ep-41/ . They can be found in VideoServers section of the page source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the website you share, there is a method called `setVideo`.
To decode the base64, it does this operation:

```js
window.atob(track.toString().substring(2));
```

In python, here is the equivalent

```py
import base64

encoded_string = "61PGlmcmFtZSB0aXRsZT0ib2sgdmlkZW8gcGxheWVyIiBzcmM9Ii8vb2sucnUvdmlkZW9lbWJlZC82MzI5MjYyOTM0NjkwP2F1dG9wbGF5PTEiIGlkPSJwbGFjZWhvbGRlciIgYWxsb3d0cmFuc3BhcmVuY3k9InRydWUiIHNjcm9sbGJhcnM9Im5vIiB0cmFuc3BhcmVudD0ieWVzIiBmcmFtZWJvcmRlcj0iMCIgYWxsb3c9ImVuY3J5cHRlZC1tZWRpYSAqOyBhdXRvcGxheTsgZnVsbHNjcmVlbiIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iNDgwIiBzY3JvbGxpbmc9Ik5vIiAgYWxsb3dmdWxsc2NyZWVuPjwvaWZyYW1lPg=="
decoded_track = base64.b64decode(encoded_string[2:]).decode('utf-8')

print(decoded_track)
```

Comment: In other words, if you strip the `61` from the beginning of the base64 data you provided in your question, your code works fine. There is no way we could guess that from the text in the question, so I'm voting to close this question as unreproducible.

Comment: @tripleee Furthermore, the string presented as being "base64" is **not** valid base64. So yes, this should be closed